# I am trying to remove numbers that are either preceded by or followed by a space but in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
string = "hello 2i a th3re 4"
remove1 = string.replace(re.search('[0-9 ]\d', string).group(0), ' ')
print(remove1.strip())

Expected output: "hello i a th3re"
Actual output: "hello i a th3re 4"
```

What might I be doing wrong? my regex is ignoring the last character in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.search('[0-9 ]\d', string).group(0)` will only give you first match. Since you want to replace multiple matches you will have to use `re.sub`.

```
import re
string = "hello 2i a th3re 4"
print(re.sub('\s\d|\d\s',' ',string))
print(re.sub('\s\d+|\d+\s',' ',string)) # if multiple digits need to be replaced.
# the regex '\s\d|\d\s' is like <space><number> or <number><space>.
# \s is for space. \d is for number. '|' is for or.
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
string = "hello 2i a th3re 4"
re.sub('( \d+)|(\d+ )', '', string)
```

```
'helloi a th3re'
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `re.sub`. `str.replace` only works with single string replacements:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "hello 2i a th3re 4"
>>> re.sub('[0-9 ]\d', " ", string).strip()
hello i a th3re
```

Comment: it will match `3` in `th3re`

Comment: still it will match `33` in `th33re`